# How can I troubleshoot a 500 error when attempting to load a GIF image after deploying using cyclic?

Tags: javascript, html, image, deployment, gif

In my html file:

`<img class="imagesit " src="images/sit_AdobeExpress.gif" width="320px" height="200px">`

I have an image in my html file. After I use cyclic to link my github and deploy the repository which contains html file and javascript file, the website work normally except the GIF image doesn't show up.

It appears the error status code: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ().

In my js file:

```
const express = require("express");

const bodyPaser = require("body-parser");

const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
```

The images folder is in the public folder. All the images work normally except the GIF image doesn't show up.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this GIF has a particular name? Something with weird characters?